Getting Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed - in Ocelot on .NET 8.0
While executing the API gateway (micro services) using Ocelot, I'm getting this exception:
warn: Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HN3PALTATQMC:00000001, previousRequestId: No PreviousRequestId, message: 'Error Code: UnableToCompleteRequestError 

Message: Error making http request, exception: 

System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

         at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)
         at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
         at System.UriBuilder.get_Uri()
         at Ocelot.Request.Middleware.DownstreamRequest.ToHttpRequestMessage()
         at Ocelot.Requester.MessageInvokerHttpRequester.GetResponse(HttpContext httpContext) errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/gateway/api/V1/SSL/GenrateToken, request method: POST'

This is the ocelot.json file:
{
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7254"
    //"RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId"
  },
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 443
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ]
    }, 
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/api/V1/SSL/GenrateToken",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/MasterAPI/api/v1/services/SSL/Token/GenrateToken",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHttpMethod": "POST",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "https://itapsuat.sslcapsec.com",
          "Port": 443
        }
      ],
      "SwaggerKey": "Token",
      "RateLimitOptions": {
        "EnableRateLimiting": true,
        "Period": "10s",
        "PeriodTimespan": 10,
        "Limit": 3,
        "HttpStatusCode": 429
      }
    }
  ],
  "SwaggerEndPoints": [
    {
      "Key": "Main",
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "MasterAPI",
          "Version": "v1",
          "Url": "https://localhost:7254/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I'm trying to access the API which is already hosted in IIS. If I try to execute DownstreamPath path via Postman, it works fine. However while accessing the same API using gateway upstream, I'm getting the exception shown above.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
I'm trying to create an API gateway using ASP.NET Core 8.
I'm expecting to get same response via API gateway (micro services)
